# LINQ Select one column Where on another column

Tags: linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I prefer the Query Method syntax but sometimes it seems so much harder.  In SQL language I can easily select a single column and have a where clause condition on another column.

```sql
SELECT UserName FROM VendorsTagged WHERE ProfileID=@pid
```

In LINQ Query Comprehension syntax I can easily translate this to:

```cs
string[] names = (from v in _db.VendorsTagged
                  where v.ProfileID == pid
                  select v.UserName).ToArray();
```

In LINQ Query Method syntax I cant get it to work.  If I attempt to add a where clause to the query below it seems to require that column to also be in the select clause, which is not the result I want.  Any ideas?

```cs
string[] names = _db.VendorsTagged.Select(s => s.UserName).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
string[] names = _db.VendorsTagged
                    .Where(v => v.ProfileId == pid)
                    .Select(v => v.UserName).ToArray();
```

That's the equivalent of your query comprehension syntax example and should work the same way.

Comment: OK, it appears my mistake was the order, I tried many variations with select first and the where at the end. If you flip them in the above example, it won't work - go figure.  This is counter-intuitive to someone that is used to SQL.  Thx

Comment: @Vic it may seem counter-intuitive at first, but I think the point is that you specify what you're selecting from and then  how to filter it, then specify which parts of the data to return in the sequence. SQL is actually a bit backwards if you think about it.